# Alcance de variables

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo scraping con el paquete `fabpot/goutte` y con el método `each` no tiene alcance la variable `$config` no se como hacerlo para no tener que declararla nuevamente dentro del método.

```
$config = Config::get('scraper.small_appliances');
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $config['url']);

$products = $crawler->filter($config['item'])->each(function($node) {

    // única forma que he encontrado para que funcione
    // $config = Config::get('scraper.small_appliances'); 

    $price = $node->filter($config['price'])->first()->html();
    $name = $node->filter($config['name'])->first()->html();

    return [
        "price" => $price,
        "name" => $name
    ];
});
```

por si vale de algo pongo el método aqui

```
   /**
     * Calls an anonymous function on each node of the list.
     *
     * The anonymous function receives the position and the node wrapped
     * in a Crawler instance as arguments.
     *
     * Example:
     *
     *     $crawler->filter('h1')->each(function ($node, $i) {
     *         return $node->text();
     *     });
     *
     * @param \Closure $closure An anonymous function
     *
     * @return array An array of values returned by the anonymous function
     */
    public function each(\Closure $closure)
    {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($this->nodes as $i => $node) {
            $data[] = $closure($this->createSubCrawler($node), $i);
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- El método `each` tiene por dentro una función anónima con su propio *scope*
- Entonces debes indicarle que use dicha propiedad pasándola al método `use`

Quedando así

```
each(función(node) use($config)......
```

**Referencias**

- [Funciones anónimas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Llevaba demasiado tiempo sin tocar php, me tengo que desintoxicar de javascript un poco. Solucionado!